# How can I override Android WebView to use custom Accept-Language header?

Tags: android, android-webview

Is is possible to override Android WebView to use custom Accept-Language header?

Answer (score 10):

The current implementation of `WebView` already allows you to add headers using the following syntax:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Accept-Language", "fr_fr");
mWebView.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com", headers);
```

See [`WebView.loadUrl()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29) for more information.

Comment: [`Override`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm) is the wrong keyword in this context. Instead you are adding additional headers.

Comment: Thanks, replaced by overload :)

Comment: Edited slightly to avoid confusing.